# bind Day (1-31) to dropdown programmatically and 0's to day < 10?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the current method in a helper file to bind monthly days to a dropdown and I wonder how I should modify it to add a leading 0 to 1-9?

```
public DropDownList PopulateDay(DropDownList ddlControlDay)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i = i + 1)
        ddlControlDay.Items.Add(i.ToString("D2"));
        return ddlControlDay;
}
```

I could convert to string, check length/modify and parse to int but is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format `"D02"` will pad with zeroes up to the limit. See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Using LINQ, it might be:

```
blah.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1,30).Select(x => x.ToString("D02"));
// or with Items.AddRange, perhaps
```

Happy coding.

---

And please fix the formatting of your code and/or use braces on the loop. I *always* use braces because then there is no "fake dangling code" like in the post :-)